# How to specify a kernel to refind?

Tags: boot, efi

How to tell refind to load a specific kernel ? I got the following line :

```
"linux" "rw nomodeset root=/dev/sda1 initrd=initrd.img"
```

But how come that I don't have a `kernel=` parameter to tell what kernel to use those parameters with ?

Answer (score 5):

That looks like an entry in `refind_linux.conf`. If so, that file applies to all the kernels in a directory. If a directory holds multiple kernels, rEFInd "folds" them into a single entry on its main menu by default. If you hit F2 or Insert, you'll see options for all the other kernels. (If `refind_linux.conf` has more than one line, each kernel will have multiple entries, one for each line in `refind_linux.conf`.)

If you prefer to see multiple entries on the rEFInd main menu, one for each kernel, you can achieve this result by editing the `refind.conf` file (usually in `/boot/efi/EFI/refind` or `/boot/EFI/refind`): Uncomment the `fold_linux_kernels` line and ensure the value is set to `false`.