# Substitution of kernel version to rEFInd without autodetection

Tags: linux, boot, manjaro, refind

Recently I moved to a rEFInd boot loader. I changed my theme to initramfs by adding `include  path/to/theme.conf` to the end of refind.conf. I want to disable autodetection of some kernels(or delete them via `minus` when loading because they are unnecessary)

This is my `/boot`:

```
efi                                intel-ucode.img      vmlinuz-5.3-x86_64
initramfs-5.3-x86_64-fallback.img  linux53-x86_64.kver  vmlinuz-5.4-x86_64
initramfs-5.3-x86_64.img           linux54-x86_64.kver  vmlinuz-5.4-x86_64.png
initramfs-5.4-x86_64-fallback.img  memtest86+
initramfs-5.4-x86_64.img           refind_linux.conf
```

How can I detect the version of my kernel? Without help of `refind_linux.conf`

I want to set the config in `refind.conf`, for instance:

```
menuentry "Manjaro" {
    icon     /EFI/refind/themes/initramfs/icons/os_manjaro.png
    volume   "SYSTEM"
    loader   "/boot/vmlinuz-VERSION_HERE"
    initrd   "/boot/initramfs-VERSION_HERE.img"
    options  "root=UUID=XXXX rw quiet apparmor=1 security=apparmor udev.log_priority=3"
    submenuentry "Boot using fallback initramfs" {
        initrd "/boot/initramfs-VERSION_HERE-fallback.img"
    }
    submenuenrty "Boot to single-user mode" {
        add_options "single"
    }
    submenuentry "Boot with minimal options" {
         options "ro root=UUID=XXXX"
    }
}
```

`os_manjaro.png` I photoshoped by myself. It works correctly.

Any extra information I can add if u ask me in comments(I don't know what information I missed)

I heared that such stuff can be deal via `postinst.d` and bash/zsh script, but I didn't find a documentation on this feature

I checked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1051064/how-to-specify-a-kernel-to-refind) question and this question is not a duplicate